# Is any needs to create a simple login view when using djangorestframework-jwt obtain_jwt_token views?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt, pyjwt

Basically I want to developed a system where user logged in using username and password using 'JSONWebTokenAuthentication'.That's way I am use 'django rest framework JWT'.Before i was create an accounts app where user can registration and login using there username and password.
In **account/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url('^login/$', UserLoginApiView.as_view(), name='login'),
url('^register/$', UserCreateApiView.as_view(), name='register'),
```

]

In **mainproject/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

url(r'^api/auth/token/', obtain_jwt_token),

url(r'^api/users/', include("account.urls", namespace='user_api')),
```

]

When i was open **'api/auth/token/'**  This URL. it shows username field and password field in the browserable api it's ok coz it is built in view djangorestframework-jwt.If username & password match in db that's provided a token.

My question is when i use my own login view .If  using 'djangorestframework-jwt' *obtain_jwt_token views in api/auth/token/*

Only registration is enough to create an user. Is any needs to create an extra login view if we use djangorestframework-jwt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do registration using username and password just use api/auth/token to login. It gives you jwt-token which you can use to authenticate with other class and views.

Comment: when using djangorestframework-jwt no need to create extra login  views am i right because jwt already provided.In that case only registration(using username&password) view is enough.Is it?

Comment: Yes it is enough.